# MVVM WPF empty user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm facing some problem trying to implement a loading spinner from here: https://github.com/blackspikeltd/Xaml-Spinners-WPF

My MainWindow is simply a wrapper where I load different user control controlled by a button:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.Desktop.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Project.Desktop.Helpers.Animations"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Project.Desktop.Views"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Project.Desktop.ViewModels"
    Title="Project" Height="580" Width="1024" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None" MouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseLeftButtonDownMove">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WelcomeVM}">
            <views:Welcome />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:GameSelectVM}">
            <views:GameSelect />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid>
       <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I copied the xml into a user control view which i created in my project and referenced like this:

```
xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Project.Desktop.Helpers.Animations"
```

and then i tried to access user control with

```
<animations:LoadingAnimation HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

The problem is that i cannot see the loading spinner, it's like doesn't exist, i believe there's a conflict between other user control but i'm not able to fix it, mostly because i'm new to wpf and xml.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe i found a solution, i need to define a datacontext for his own user control:

```
<animations:LoadingAnimation DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```